# Unknown column in order clause

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

`#1054 - Unknown column 'default_ps_products.manufacturer_id' in 'order clause'`

Why am I getting the above error with the statement below it works fine without the `p` in the statement and I am not using an order clause?

```
SELECT * FROM `default_ps_products` p WHERE p.`manufacturer_id` = 2
```

Comment: you need to use the `ALIAS` instead of the tablename since you have define an alias on the table. eg `p.manufacturer_id`

Comment: @JW웃 I have tried `SELECT * FROM `default_ps_products` p WHERE p.manufacturer_id = 2` still the same error

Comment: I can't see a reason you'd be getting this message without an actual `ORDER BY`. Are you sure this is the actual query executing when you get the error?

Comment: are you using backtick or single quote? can you post the whole query?

Comment: @JW웃 I am using ` and not '

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes I am

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Is `default_ps_products` a table or a view? Also, are you executing the query from code or straight from phpmyadmin?

Comment: Show us the table structure of default_ps_products

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson phpMyAdmin image is without the p http://d.pr/i/ysuD

Comment: @JessMcKenzie If you set an alias `p` for the table, you'll need to also `ORDER BY` p.`manufacturer_id`. You're effectively removing the name `default_ps_products` and adding the name `p`, so _all_ references to `default_ps_products` need to be changed.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Please post an answer and ill accept

Comment: @JessMcKenzie It's basically the same thing as JW said as the very first comment, so if he doesn't want to add an answer, I will in a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you posted a partial query this wasn't obvious from the start, but your [full query](http://d.pr/i/ysuD) makes it clear;

```
SELECT *
FROM default_ps_products
WHERE manufacturer_id=2
ORDER BY `default_ps_products`.`manufacturer_id` ASC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

When you add an alias to `default_ps_products` table in the select, you can't selectively use the alias only in the `WHERE` clause, you'll also need to change the `ORDER BY` to use the same alias. The full query should in other words be;

```
SELECT *
FROM default_ps_products p
WHERE p.manufacturer_id=2
ORDER BY p.`manufacturer_id` ASC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Answer (score 12):

To solve this use `SELECT p.* FROM` instead of `SELECT * FROM`.

The reason is that phpMyAdmin is adding an ORDER BY to your query for the first column in the results grid. Because of the alias, the code that does this fails.

This issue reproduces on phpMyAdmin 4.0.6. I don't know the status on the latest 4.2.5

Comment: You can get this error even if there is no ORDER BY clause.  This answer solves that problem; Isaksson's answer does not.

Answer (score 3):

Open your phpmyadmin. Click on your selected database. Now you have a list of all tables on right side. Click on structure of `default_ps_products` table. Now you see a structure of it. Now Click on SQL tab and execute query as 'SELECT * FROM default_ps_products ORDER BY '.
Once you execute this query, Now resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine. there is not any error when i run this query. there is nothing wrong with query.

`SELECT * FROM default_ps_products AS  p WHERE p.manufacturer_id = 2`
it working fine.:)

Answer (score 0):

when use `@Query(nativeQuery = true)`, should use underline format ,just like this `"Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "update_time")))"`, else should use camel properties in entity ,like this `"Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "updateTime")))"`

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin started showing this error suddenly on one table. only fix was to rename column id to id2 then back. even deleting the table and making new copy  didn't help